# How do I find out the width of my nav so I can set it to be the exact same as my image?

Tags: html, css

I placed an image in a website im trying to make but its width is too big it goes off screen, I want it to be the the same width as my nav, but I didn't set any width for my NAV so how do I find out what size I will place?  Thank you in advance

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWLuD.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Place your nav and image in a div and set the image width to the 100% of its container so it will adjust automatically.

```
<div class="container">
   <nav>
   </nav>
   <img src="whatever" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using little bit of CSS it will automatically take the size of your screen or browser

```css
body {
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/08/05/10/32/ice-cream-410330__340.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```